# HTMLUnit submit form not working

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have a jsp file with the following code:

```
<form name="postToChatPicMsg" method="post" action="/api/media/postToChatPicMsg" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <br>udid:<input type="text" name="udid" value="54321dsfsdfsdfasdas">
                    <br>token:<input type="text" name="token" value="32cfa8b259c38bdd95f8cede17acb366">
                    <br>mediaFile:<input type="file" name="mediaFile">
                    <br>message:<input type="text" name="message" value="">
                    <br><input type="submit" name="submitButton">
                </form>
```

This works from jsp. now to automate test , I am trying to user HTMLUnit and I try to do the following

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage p;
    try {
        p = c.getPage("http://localhost:55080/api.jsp");
        HtmlForm uploadForm = p.getFormByName("postToChatPicMsg");
        HtmlFileInput fileInput = uploadForm.getInputByName("mediaFile");
        fileInput.setValueAttribute("/src/test/resources/logo.jpg");
           ((HtmlSubmitInput)uploadForm).getInputByName("submitButton")).click());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The call to the api returns an xml back. I was expecting the call to go through and hit the server and i can see the activity in logs. But nothing seem to happen.

This is first time i am trying to use HTMLUnit.

Comment: Is there anything important in the xml you receive?

Comment: just receive the success message. I cant change the response for xml since the code is already live.

Comment: The code you provided shoud be executing this action `/api/media/postToChatPicMsg` in the server. That must be returning the xml. I don't see what is it that is not working properly. Can you clarify?

Comment: i dont see image being uploaded and all the log statements i have being executed.